# A good way to store this browser versions - Django/Postgresql

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have this data:

> Firefox 3.6

There are 3 items

- name
- max version
- min version

---

I am storing it this way:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    browser_name = models.CharField(...)
    browser_max_version = models.IntegerField(...)
    browser_min_version = models.IntegerField(...)
```

or alternative

```
class Browser(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(...)
    max_version = models.IntegerField(...)
    min_version = models.IntegerField(...)

class MyModel(models.Model):

    browser = models.ForeignKey(Browser)
```

---

Is there any clever way to store the value in 1 field and making it parsable at the same time?

I know this might sound weird, but I wonder if there are any alternative to building 1 million models to represent data.

---

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Shouldn't it better be a `FloatField` if you want to store something like `3.6`?

Comment: @lazerscience: `FloatField` doesn't work :) as `3.11 should be > than 3.6`. Thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it parseable, but probably not indexable. For example, you could concatenate the values together separated by semicolons (or some other character), then simply split the string to get the values back. "Firefox 3.6" would become "Firefox;3;6". While this is somewhat easier to parse, it doesn't provide much of an advantage over the original formatting.

The big caveat with this approach is that the column wouldn't be indexable in a very granular way. For example, you couldn't ask for all versions of Firefox. PostgreSQL allows for some very advanced indexing which, I believe, would allow you to create the required indexes, but I don't know of any way you could access the indexes via Django's ORM.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of `MyModel` in the second example? The one table `Browser` is all you need. Why on earth would you need 'millions' of models? Or are you talking about rows in a table?

```
class Browser(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(...)
    max_version = models.IntegerField(...)
    min_version = models.IntegerField(...)
```

is fine